# Set of solutions for a binomial inequality

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

I bumped into the following inequality:

$${a-b\choose c}{a\choose c}^{-1} \le \exp\left(-\frac{bc}{a}\right)$$

Playing with it a little bit, trying to bound it asymptotically for large $a$'s, using Stirling's approximation, I ended up with nothing. <strike>Finally I decided to put some numbers and check it, and figured out it is wrong. Moreover: it looked like it is *always* wrong.</strike>

Can you prove this inequality?

**Edit:** since it wasn't clear, I'll add that $a,b,c$ are all positive integers.

**Edit:** I also forgot to add the assumption $a>b>c$.

Comment: Now, how's the inequality supposed to be? You said from your examples LHS is always greater RHS?

Comment: But you may have a mix up because what you say is: in my experimentation, I always found that $L\le R$ is false. So, this would mean $L>R$. But then you ask: does it ever hold that $L\ge R$. That confuses me...

Comment: But, if you take $a=5,b=4,c=3$, then $L<R$.

Comment: Sure, I didn't consider the cases where $a-b<c$. Anyway, I guess I did some calculation mistakes, as for $a=4$, $b=2$, $c=1$ it also holds that $L<R$.

Comment: Actually, I always find that $L<R$ and I can't believe that $L\ge R$ ever (can you give an example for this)? E.g., for $(a,b,c)=(10,5,4)$ we have $L=0.02381<0.13534=R$.

Comment: I take your intuition and try to prove it now. Thanks.

Comment: Now, you have to add constraints on $a,b,c$ again, for otherwise it's not true ... :)

Comment: Sure, sorry... added it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will now prove the inequality, using probability techniques. I wonder if this is the easiest way to show it...

Theorem 2.10 in $\color{blue}{[1]}$ shows Chernoff-type bounds may be applied to Hypergeometric distributed random variables. In particular, if $X$ is a random variable, $X\sim\text{Hypergeometric}(N,K,n)$, $\mu=\mathbb{E}(X)=nKN^{-1}$, then
\begin{equation*}
  \mathbb{P}(X\le \mu-a) \le \exp\left(-\mu\varphi\left(\frac{-a}{\mu}\right)\right)
\end{equation*}
for $a\ge 0$ and $\varphi=(1+x)\ln(1+x)-x$ for $x\ge -1$ (and $\varphi(x)=\infty$ for $x<-1$).

Now, let $X\sim\text{Hypergeometric}(a,b,c)$. The LHS of our inequality is then simply $\mathbb{P}(X=0)$. While $\varphi$ is not well defined for $x=-1$, we may continuously extend it to have $\varphi(-1)=1$. Hence
  \begin{equation*}
    \frac{{a-b\choose c}}{{a\choose c}}
    = \mathbb{P}(X\le \mu-\mu) \le \exp\left(-\mu\varphi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\mu}\right)\right)
    = \exp(-\mu) = \exp\left(-\frac{bc}{a}\right).
  \end{equation*}

**References**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ S. Janson, T. Łuczak and A. Ruciński, *Random Graphs*, New York, Wiley (2000)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I don't know if you want LHS $\ge $ RHS or LHS $\le $ RHS.

But here is an example: If you take $a=b+1=c+2$ --- e.g. $a=5,b=4,c=3$, then LHS $=0$ and the RHS is positive. So LHS $<$ RHS.

I think that given your restrictions $a>b>c$, it can never hold that LHS $\ge $ RHS.

Comment: $a=b=c$ is not allowed.

Comment: Alright, I see, he excluded this case .... I have to check then again.

Comment: I didn't read $a>b>c$ ... so all my examples are wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Without further restrictions on $a,b,c$ neither inequality can be correct:
Let $l(a,b,c)$ the LHS and $r(a,b,c)$ the RHS, then
$$l(3,2,1)=1/3 < r(3,2,1) = \exp(-2/3) \approx 0.513417$$
but
$$l(3,2,-1/2)=35/24 \approx 1.458333 > r(3,2,-1/2) = \exp(1/3)  \approx 1.395612$$

Comment: I apologize; I have added the restriction $a>b>c$ and all are positive integers.